# How to make type of conditional object property to not be undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, inferred-type

I have the following object which has a conditional property on it

```
function someCondition() {
  return Math.random() > .5 ? true : false
}

const DICTIONARY = {
  propertyA: 'propertyA' as const,
  ...(someCondition() && {
    propertyB: 'propertyB' as const,
  }),
};
```

The intent here is to have an object where the `propertyB` may or may not exist on it, but if it does it should only have the type of `propertyB`, which in TS would be expressed as

```
{
    propertyB?: "propertyB";
    propertyA: "propertyA";
}
```

However the inferred type is actually

```
{
    propertyB?: "propertyB" | undefined;
    propertyA: "propertyA";
}
```

which is not the intent of the above code. `propertyB` should either exist or not exist (`?:`) and if it exists it should only be `propertyB` and not also `undefined`

I have tried to strictly define the type of `DICTIONARY` by hand, but it always ends up with the wrong type.

How can I narrow it down to just an optional property which cannot be `undefined`?

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYGEEBMawIAUAlIgN4BQiiAThlCLUgLICGUAFgHS1ti50pRAD5E3AKyIA-Iii0QGRAC5EwNgBtkGSgF9KlCAmRREAEQCSWACoWA8gDkAggCUAmogC8FaogAOtHB+GLRQAJ5OqgDkAUEh4U5RiGzIiEZgJgA0vty5RKiYOAIE8GDCAGTlPjQ0scGhYQBC0XXxTUkpacZQ2TS6JNm6ANxAA)

Comment: [Enable `exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://tsplay.dev/N5Ld0w)

Comment: Neat, that was it, cheers!